# Lucidworks fusion 3.1.0 error starting api

Tags: api, windows-7, fusion, lucidworks

I am trying to run fusion but I keep getting this error: `error starting api: api service (pid 8156) failed`

zookeeper and solr are started but when it comes to the api i get this error. Any insights are appreaciated.

Answer (score 1):

Run cmd as admin and then try to run the command if that doesn't still work then go to conf/conf.properties and search for port number and change it to some free port on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Please start the fusion.cmd as Administrator. I faced the same issue and got resolved when I tried as administrator.